# FAQs worth adding

Tags: discussion

Right now there isn't much in the FAQ beyond the standard boiler plate, but I think that as we move though the beta we might want to expand it a bit with questions like the following:

> [How to write hiragana and katakana in Windows?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/289/how-to-write-hiragana-and-katakana-in-windows)

It is a bit of a technical support question, but new users to the site might find it useful.

Comment: Actually, who has rights to edit the FAQ anyway? Or is that another thing that's controlled by one's reputation?

Comment: @rcjsuen - I'm not sure, I think it is limited to moderators.

Comment: @rcjsuen: Moderator can and are encouraged to edit the faq. Pro Tem moderators will be appointed to this site, starting after about its second week: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/

Comment: Removing FAQ on this... other FAQ questions handle everything mentioned here.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in another comment thread, making a mention of rikai[chan|kun] will be really important for beginners who haven't heard of the tool and don't know much kanji.

Answer (score 0):

Another item that might be worth mentioning is the [Furigana Inserter](http://code.google.com/p/itadaki/) add-on for Firefox.

Comment: I added it to our [resources](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/757/29) page. Please correct it if I described it incorrectly (I don't run firefox)

Answer (score 0):

I would add the advice:

Do not randomly accept or upvote an answer after only a few hours (sometimes a few minutes) just because the writer is particularly eloquent or has a high reputation. Leave the question open 1 day or more.

I've seen a lot of accepted or upvoted answers being either completely wrong or lacking a lot of details (1 or two sentences) as if the answerer did a 1 minute google search, picked up something that would fit as a quick answer and just posted his guess to be the first to get upvotes like it is a popularity contest. (oh and I've seen downvoted quality answers as well...)