# Updating the FAQ

Tags: discussion

According to [Updating the FAQ for a StackExchange site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61996/updating-the-faq-for-a-stackexchange-site) it is now possible for moderators to edit the FAQ, but I do not know if this is also the case for beta sites.

If yes, could we at least put a few things, even if it's imperfect?
I think that a few examples of "good questions" and "bad questions" would be a good start.

Sounds good?

Answer (score 4):

Over the last few weeks, I've attempted to synthesize the most common issues on the site into a short series of FAQ articles on meta. I think I've been reasonably successful at this point.

Could we have the following faq-proposed questions marked FAQ, or an explanation given for why they shouldn't be?

1. [How should I format my questions on Japanese Language SE?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/806/how-should-i-format-my-questions-on-jlu)
2. [What questions are not allowed on Japanese Language SE?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-and-usage)

---

Could we make the first section of our site-FAQ look like this:

> Japanese Language and Usage - Stack Exchange is for students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the Japanese language.
>
> Please look around to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to ask and answer your own question.
>
> - [How should I format my questions on JLU?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/806)
> - [What are the attributes of a good question?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/732)
> - [What Japanese-related questions are not allowed on JLU?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796)
> - [What are some resources to help me with Japanese study?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/)
>
>   - (resource questions are offtopic on JLU, but we hope this list will be useful)
> - [What does 'too localized' mean for JLU?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/400)

---

These seem to be the major points that we should be covering in a FAQ. The remaining areas that need covering are, in my opinion:

1. Setting up and using an IME
2. A fixed up version of [this question about names for parts of speech](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352)

---

Looking over the [FAQ tagged questions](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq), I guess I'm curious why several of them are actually tagged FAQ at this point:

1. [FAQs Worth Adding](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62) - This always seemed more discussion than FAQ itself. The resources listed in this question have been added to the larger resources question.
2. [This Question](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/502) - Somewhat wierdly, this is a FAQ for meta-users, but actually putting something reasonable there will cause it to no longer be a question at all.
3. [The intonation markup question](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/403) - There is no consensus. When there is, it will be absorbed by the "how should I format my questions?" FAQ item
4. [The old furigana thread](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339) - is now quite misleading and confusing for new users, since it was created while we were still deciding on a format
5. Several others are questionable... but I'd leave that up to others

Comment: A "how to set up and use an IME" covering different OS's would be great... I came to this site looking for how to type japanese, and all I see are closed questions making the website very off-putting.  Now I'm too afraid to ask anything.

Answer (score 2):

The first [section](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) of the faq is editable by the moderators and this is definitely possible for beta sites.

The community should absolutely be figuring out what needs to go into the faq.  Come up with what should be said! (: