# Rikaisan - Rikaichan/kun for Opera

Tags: support

I don't know if this even qualifies for the meta board, but I thought I'd let the Opera lovers out there know that they no longer need to start up Firefox/Chrome when they need their favourite browser extension. :)

https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/rikaisan/?display=en

http://mathall.github.com/Rikaisan/

Answer (score 2):

I added it to the Resources section on [browser addons](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/757/29).

Comment: Cool, didn't know about that one. Just made a small edit there.