# Is the "learning" tag misleading?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

After taking a look through posts that had this tag, I found that quite a few of them either get closed or migrated to meta. Except for users who have been here for awhile, this tag seems to suggest to new users that posts for "best practices" or "resources" fit on the main site.

For example, the previously closed question [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6174/1328) uses the "learning" tag.

The tag description currently reads:

> Improving your proficiency in the Japanese language.

Could this description be improved so as to not be open-ended? Correct uses of the tag tend to consist of those relating to the Japanese society, school system, etc,.

EDIT: It is probably best to have a list of questions that use this tag appropriately and those that do not. I made links to some of the questions that might help define the tag. If any links should be added, removed, changed, or switched, please comment.

**Appropriate for JLU:**

[Learning order for kana?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5346/1328)

[Linguistics and Japanese study](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5060/1328)

[Are there any risks in self-learning the kana?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3294/1328)

[What is the learning curve for learning Japanese writing?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2532/1328)

[Is Japanese that lacks proofreading likely to contain bad spelling or grammar?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3176/1328)

**Appropriate for Meta:**

[How to improve kana reading speed?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/852/1328)

[Anki decks for studying Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5238/1328)

[What is a good series of books/programs to start learning from, if any?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4545/1328)

[How can I improve my Japanese vocabulary, grammar, and listening skills?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4413/1328)

[What Japanese lullabys are available to provide early Japanese exposure to children?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3738/1328)

Comment: I'd be in favor of adding a sentence to the wiki saying that such questions are usually off-topic for the main site. Also, can you provide links to examples of on-topic learning questions?