# Place to learn Japanese but in Romaji?

Tags: discussion, learning

I know how bad it is to learn Japanese in Romaji, but I can't learn alphabets for some reason, so is there a place to learn Japanese but in Romaji? like grammars, words and such....

Comment: Have you considered learning via speaking and listening instead of focusing on writing?

Comment: @snailboat No, never... Should I?

Comment: You definitely should,

Comment: You might have a look at this: http://wiki.xxiivv.com/Japanese%20guide

Comment: Are you saying learning kanji/kana is too difficult, so you want to learn romaji instead? (kanji/kana usually aren't referred to as "alphabets") You should add what your goal in learning Japanese is (reading/writing/speaking). It might be easier to respond to specific concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As snailboat said, learning via speaking and listening would work towards your goals.

That being said, you can use the search query "japanese romaji grammar" on Google and there seems to be a bunch of results there. Just in case the query doesn't work for you, some of the top results that appear to have or be almost entirely in romaji are http://www.learn-japanese.info and http://easyjapanese.org.

That being said, you should always be careful when using learning resources like that online, and compare multiple resources to make sure you aren't getting incomplete and/or incorrect information. In addition, I personally don't use any rо̄maji resources, so I can't vouch for their authenticity and reliability. In addition, there are different methods of romanization, so you may see "tsu" and "tu", and they are the same thing, another example would be "ji" and "zi" or "dzu" and "du".

In addition, I suggest you take a look at the "Japanese for Busy People" which has both a rо̄maji and kana (just kana, no kanji) version. The first edition of the book only had rо̄maji version though.

Comment: *This doesn't answer your question so I'm keeping this separate and you can ignore this if you want:* Learning new alphabets and syllabaries is hard, but very worth while. In my experience, if you learn to write a language in the native script, it is always easier, since it is essentially "tailored" to suit the language. Since I've done it myself, I will suggest that if you ever do again want to try to learn kana, to write each kana over and over again until it is essentially etched into your muscle memory. I did this myself in order to write faster while maintaining neatness, and it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is already quite old but since this thread is easily found with google, I'll add my answer anyways, maybe it's helpful for others. Pandacoder already pointed you to resources for beginners. If you'd like to continue with roumaji beyond this point, my anki addon could help you. It can convert Japanese text to latin characters, among other things. I've been using this myself for a long time now and found it to work very well. Note that the script conversion is prone to errors though, you shouldn't use it for content without audio: https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/2110939339

I wish you success and fun in case you're still studying.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the somewhat older "Japanese, The Spoken Language" program by Jordan/Noda. It goes quite a bit farther than most introductory Japanese language programs using its kunrei-variant romaji. We reference it on our resources FAQ: [Resources for learning Japanese](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese/766#766)