# Are mneomonic suggestions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Are suggestions for remembering Kana/Kanji on-topic on this site?

I know there are many resources available online for Kana mnemonics (which have helped me a lot up to now), but I am struggling to think of a way to remember the difference between ね, れ, わ.

I'm normally capable of creating my own mnemonics and I'd probably get there in the end but I think it would be good to have a few suggestions to help me and future visitors to the site.

Comment: Another Kanji Such That Noone Here Kan Yell Real WInner

Comment: @CraigHicks Is that an example of a useless mnemonic, because you can never remember which of `Kanji` and `Kan` is supposed to represent マ行...?

Comment: Maybe ask on language learning stack exchange instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current consensus is that questions about study methods are off-topic. In fact, they are likely to be closed with the following "close reason"

> Questions seeking **resources** or **advice** about learning Japanese are off-topic here, but you may find our list of [resources for learning Japanese](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese) helpful.

I've always found arbitrary mnemonics useless and questions about etymology/origins helpful. With respect to the question you have in mind, you may want to take a look at [Origin of the circle in ぬ, ね, and る](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23/1628)

Of course, ね・れ・わ are derived from *kanji* with this pronunciation, namely 祢・礼・和 and the similar-looking part in ね・れ・わ on the left comes from ネ・ネ・禾...

So you can't ask "*How* do I remember this?", but you can ask "*Why* is it like this?" and maybe this is already enough to remember...

Comment: I disagree with arbitrary mnemonics being useless as an aid to memory, they have their uses but I agree that an explanation of the origin of a character is more valuable for long-term memory and understanding.

Comment: I noticed [this question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13846/difference-between-katakana-so-and-n) which I found helpful wasn't considered off-topic but I also couldn't find many questions like it which is why I was confused.