# Can someone correct a URL?

Tags: discussion, kanji

On the page at [Resources for learning Japanese](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese/1074#1074?newreg=76bf47769ffc40e1b24a78bcc68b66fb)

the URL for the Kyoto/Melbourne n-gram corpus lookup is broken. The (new) correct URL is:
http://nlp.cis.unimelb.edu.au/jwb/ngramcountswww.html

I can't edit or comment on it because I need some sorts of brownie points.

Jim Breen

Comment: I've updated the link. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! (Seems I can say things now  8D}