# Resources for searching Japanese Corpora

Tags: discussion, resources

I am trying to put together a list of useful links and resources for people who want to search various Japanese corpora. In my experience, some of the websites and interfaces are less than ideal, in terms of how user-friendly they are,  so my idea is to have a curated post here with links and user guides for each corpus or website.

I will answer my own question but I will continue to add in any information which other people provide, as long as they are happy to do so.

Comment: Related? https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese/1074#1074

Comment: Ah so mine is just a duplicate. That link is more detailed so I will delete this post. Thanks!

Comment: I thought you were going to give a visual guide to that FAQ entry, which may be useful for people who are not as comfortable around Japanese. If you decide to keep this post, I would suggest you post one guide per answer.

Answer (score 1):

..................................................................................................................................................................
**Tsukuba Web Corpus**
http://nlt.tsukuba.lagoinst.info/search/

Very user friendly, no registration required. Simply enter your search term into the box and it will produce a result which breaks down your search term by syntactic use and provides full sentences for each hit. There is also a useful feature which lists parts of speech by frequency.

[image: Tsukuba]

..................................................................................................................................................................
**The Balanced Corpus of Contemporary Written Japanese** (BCCWJ)  https://pj.ninjal.ac.jp/corpus_center/bccwj/en/

There are two free online versions - One does not require registration and the other does. The main difference between the two seems to be the use of different corpora. For example, in the registration-required version, you can also access two spoken/conversational Japanese corpora. The search function on this site is entirely in Japanese and is a little complicated if you are not used to searching a corpus.

[image: BCCWJ]

..................................................................................................................................................................