# How to approach Japanese Graded Readers?

Tags: discussion, learning

I am an absolute beginner. Only level 2 on Wanikani and I've gone through a couple of chapters in Genki. I would like to read something in Japanese and Japanese Graded Readers are famously good choices.

Given my ultra beginner status, I'm still unfamiliar with even the level 0 vocabulary. Should I wait until I know the vocabulary, or should I just translate the pages?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try level 0 and see how far you get. But my path has been: I did probably 2 textbooks (Japanese from Zero!), maybe 3, and a lot of false starts reading things too hard for me, and then I did level 0 and it was fine.

Note that in some ways level 0 has some extra difficulty because it gives scripted polite things like ganbatte and itadakimasu. The wedding one is particularly hard. But much is easier.

So here's some. I quote from memory, so no guarantees.

ようこそ！
これは、父のお箸です。
これは、お母さんのです。
これは、私の。
これは、マリアちゃんの！
ごちそうさま！

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at resources here: [Resources for learning Japanese](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese/769#769)

I suggest using the kanji teacher app (ios) to learn hiragana and katakana (meories and draw them) then get a japanese teacher to help guide you through the genki book (and help you do the practice questions) as they can correct you on pronunciations and your writing. However use the link above to find what is best for you.