# Suggestions on how to translate handwriting I can't read

Tags: discussion

An artist I follow on twitter recently uploaded a video where they write some text on a piece of paper. 
Now, I understand some of it, but most of it I'm not good enough to read, and so I can't put it into google translate.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to approach translating in situations similar to this one where I can't use software due to handwriting being too bad for me to read.

I was hoping to get maybe suggestions for websites or communities in which I could get translations of videos very quickly, free or paid.

I am not providing the link to the video I want translated here anymore, to make it clear that I'm not asking for you to translate it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The video won't load for me, so from my point of view this is unfortunately impossible to answer, on-topic or off-.

Comment: I think you are better of trying a different community. E.g. https://www.reddit.com/r/translator/

Comment: I removed the link to the text that I'm trying to translate, and I changed the question to more reflect that I'm not looking for a translation, rather I'm looking for suggestions on how to approach translating in situations similar to this one where I can't use software due to handwriting being too bad for me to read. I was hoping to get maybe suggestions for websites or communities in which I could get translations of videos very quickly, free or paid.

Comment: @Christer Thank you for your suggestion! I posted the text on r/translator and got the translation within hours! Thank you for being the only person to actually give a constructive answer. If you can, please upgrade your comment into an answer so that I can mark the question as answered.

Comment: I feel doing that would be inappropriate, but thanks for the offer. Glad someone helped you out though! :)

Comment: Well, the question is how I would go about translating something like this, so you did answer it. I don't think it would be inappropriate.

Comment: This question is more suitable on the [meta] since they allow off-site resources on there. Wonder if mods are comfortable in migrating it...

Comment: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese