# Where to find simple example sentences

Tags: discussion

Does anyone know any website or corpus (apart from jisho.org, weblio, reverso context or glosbe) where for a given word I can get lots of simple sentences with that word?

There are many times that when I look for examples of use of a word in jisho.org I get none or the sentences that appear are not useful to me.

After some googling I have found some pages that also give example sentences, but these are all the same as the sentences on jisho.org. :(

Could you please tell me any other website in which I could look for example sentences?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Just so you know, I think this question is off-topic for the main JL SE as it is asking about resources, but it would be fine for the meta SE.

Comment: Is there a way to send this to meta SE?

Answer (score 1):

Tsukuba Web Corpus is excellent. (http://nlt.tsukuba.lagoinst.info/search/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised no one has pointed you to the [resources page](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese/1074#1074) as it contains links to every corpus we know about.

Comment: How did you find that page?

Comment: I typed "resources" in the search bar on the Meta page. If you mean how did I know about it in the first place, someone mentioned it in a comment to a question asking for resources on the main site.

Comment: I think that's part of the problem, things like resources, question guidelines and other important pages should be obvious to find from the start page without any prior knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I often use 青空文庫 (https://www.aozora.gr.jp/) combined with google search: query with "the-word" + site:aozora.gr.jp. For example, try ["お手本"](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22%E3%81%8A%E6%89%8B%E6%9C%AC%22+site%3Aaozora.gr.jp)

Another great source is [少納言](https://shonagon.ninjal.ac.jp/), there's also [中納言](https://chunagon.ninjal.ac.jp/) with more features but requires login (free registration).