# What are authoritative Japanese grammar books written in Japanese?

Tags: discussion, resources

I know Kojien is the most authoritative dictionary.

What are some authoritative grammar books written in Japanese?

Comment: We handle questions about resources here on our meta site. Currently our [list of resources](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/756/1628) does not list any grammar books in Japanese, so I think collecting suggestions would be useful.