# This is not an opinion. It should not be closed for being opinion based

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I am not a frequent user here. But I have to say having my [well-recieved question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/93543/list-of-japanese-idioms-sorted-by-popularity) ([now migrated](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2279/list-of-japanese-idioms-sorted-by-popularity)) closed with no explanation other than that it is "opinion-based" speaks really poorly for the current system, whatever it is.

My question is not even a little bit opinion based. I seek a list of common phrases (such as idioms) that is organized by frequency of use.

Am I wrong here?

Comment: I totally agree with you that your question is not opinion based, but it does seem to be a request for information about language resources. As such, maybe it would be received more favorably if you posted it here on the "meta" site instead. (If you do go that route, you might also want to consider rephrasing the question. I strongly suspect the answer to it, in its current form, is "no.")

Comment: Your original question should have been migrated to meta instead of closed. And I wish someone would pin [this meta site collection of resources](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese) somewhere on the questions page perhaps, or at least point it out to askers such as yourself because even if it doesn't answer such questions directly, there is a LOT of good info there. And it is so hard to come across most people don't seem to know it exists.

Answer (score 2):

I'll resolve it and close it under the right reason then.
It has been migrated and [this is where it is now](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2279/list-of-japanese-idioms-sorted-by-popularity)

Requests for resources are off-topic for the main site.
You can create a post here in meta or discuss in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/511/japanese-language).

This is not to say that your question does not have merit in itself.
It is a useful idea to have idioms or phrases sorted by frequency.
However, the main site's focus is on issues about the language itself, and not about the learning approaches to the language.