# List of Japanese idioms sorted by popularity

Tags: discussion, resources

I'm interested in learning common Japanese phrases like idioms.

But naturally I don't want to waste time on phrases that aren't commonly used. For instance, in English phrases like "bark up the wrong tree" might be useful to know, but not "walk around in hot porridge."

Is there a collection of phases that is organized by popularity? Even better if this is something like an Anki deck.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the level of your Japanese skill, but I suppose keywords like "小学生　慣用句" or "中学生　慣用句" would give you some helpful lists. They are not chosen based on popularity, but most probably are what most people are familiar with.

[This blog](https://ameblo.jp/macgyverisms/entry-11910354296.html) posts an Anki deck, but it seems designed for entrance exams (for secondary schools, taken by primary school pupils), so I'm not sure to what extent they are realistic.

Some lists that came top on my searches:

- [小学生が覚えておきたい慣用句](https://stupedia.tekibo.net/kanyoku/)
- [小学生のための『ことわざ』１2０選](https://yattoke.com/2017/11/22/kotowaza120/)
- [小学生向け四字熟語一覧](https://hanntaigo.main.jp/yojijyukugo/shougakusei.html)