# Sanseidō Daijirin, 3rd edition, link rot

Tags: discussion, resources, meta

The link for [Sanseidō Daijirin, 3rd edition](https://www.weblio.jp/cat/dictionary/ssdjj) [here in the resources post](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese/1496#1496) seems to have expired. Any idea where else it can be found online? Or should we remove it from the resources post?

Comment: It seems that the free dictionary was closed as of 2020/09/30. This is the [link](https://www.sanseido-publ.co.jp/sp/wbdct_close.html) I suppose it is natural to think all items related to the sanseido Daijirin was expired.