# Good Kanji book for Japanese beginner

Tags: support, kanji, learning

Could you suggest some good Kanji books for Japanese beginner?
I have checked these resources, [Resources for learning Japanese](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese), didn't find any useful ones...
Thank you!

Comment: I heard [this book](https://unkogakuen.com/books/unkokanji) is good. I haven't tried though.

Comment: I use renshuu.org  All the books needed are on the site.